# Google Apps Script for Spreadsheet - Keep getting the function () { [native code] } error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I execute my function, and it returns a function () { [native code] } error alongside the proper outputs. Example: [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgXha.jpg) [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFri.jpg)

My code:

```js
function SubmitInput() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("FORM");
  var outputS = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE")

  var values = [[inputS.getRange("C7").getValue,
                inputS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("F7").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("F9").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("F11").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("I7").getValue(),
                inputS.getRange("I9").getValue()]];
 outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 8).setValues(values);
 ClearCell();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo in your code

```
inputS.getRange("C7").getValue,¸
```

should be

```
inputS.getRange("C7").getValue(),¸
```